# Use result of filter formula twice

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

can you help me to simplify a formula, please? I am setting up an accountants sheets and need to subtract incoming payments from outgoing payments in a certain time frame. As there are several filter criteria and a lot of entries in the table, I was wondering what the best way is to do the filter only once.

[image: Here is a minimum example]

This is my filter function in F4

```
=sum(filter(B1:B8,C1:C8>=F1,C1:C8<=F2,A1:A8="expense"))-sum(filter(B1:B8,C1:C8>=F1,C1:C8<=F2,A1:A8="income"))
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xg2UM8eJuWB_-1DUhdLHe5gl_SUn72pyzJlPEY1cRqA/edit?usp=sharing) is the table for you.

Is there any way like sum(filter(expense-income))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `F4`:

```
=sum(filter(IF(A:A = "income", -1, 1) * B:B, B:B <> "", C:C >= F1, C:C <= F2))
```

[image]

Comment: I love this solution! Thank you so much :)